# qt says libxml2 is not installed on windows

Tags: c++, qt, configuration, libxml2

I have cloned a Qt project from git and when I try to build it, it says libxml2 is not installed. Thne I downloaded the libxml2 and put the bin's path to environmental variable's as described in readme. But it has not changed anything. It shows me the same error. Is there a special way of configuring libsml2 for qt?

Comment: What is the error? Which version from git did you clone?

Comment: "libxml2 is not installed, did you forget to install it" like thing. I didn't clone any libxml2. I cloned a project in github and it asks for libxml2, when I try to run it on qt.

Comment: ...ah, you're trying to build "a" Qt project, not the Qt project. Which build system does the project use? QMake, or something else?

Comment: it's qmake build system.

Comment: This question needs a lot more information to be answerable. Better add the actual commands you use, and the actual output, *to the question itself*. Also, tell what you actually installed, and to where, and how, when you installed libxml2.